# LINEAR MAPS and their representation in ordered tuple

Tags: linear-algebra

If $L:F^n\to F^m$ is linear map show that it can be written as like.

$L(x)=(f_1(x),\cdots,f_m(x))$             Where $f_j\in (F^n)' and x\in F^n$

I tried to do something involving their basis but unable to construc such functions like $f_j$'s ...

Comment: What is $(F^n)'$?

Comment: @GitGud Dual space

Comment: Sorry, or replying late, Yes, its the Dual space representation.